# Mysql count() not summing with two table JOIN and GROUP BY, in tagging scheme

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by, count

I have a scenario of questions that have tags associated with them - like StackOverflow here.  I want to list all the tags associated with a certain question along with a count for each tag that tells how many times this same tag is used/referenced by other questions.

**TAGS TABLE:** tag_id , tag_name (tag_name is unique)

**TAGS CROSS REFERENCE TABLE**: tag_id, question_id (tag_id references tag_id in tags table, and question_id in questions table).

**QUESTIONS TABLE**: question_id, question.

The code I have lists all tags associated with a particular question_id, but the count()/num of the total usage of each tag is always "1", but should be totaling different numbers...

```
$question_id = 268;
$sql = 'SELECT tags.tag_id, tag_name, count(tags.tag_id) AS num
        FROM tags LEFT JOIN tags_x 
        ON tags.tag_id = tags_x.tag_id 
        WHERE tags_x.question_id = ? 
        GROUP BY tags.tag_name';    
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute([$question_id]); 
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(pdo::FETCH_ASSOC);
$out = '';
foreach($result as $row){
    $tag_id = $row['tag_id'];
    $tag_name = $row['tag_name'];
    $num = $row['num'];//count of all items referencing same tagname
    echo $tag_id.' - '.$tag_name.' - '.$num.'<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option uses a correlated subquery to compute the count of questions per tag. I would expect better efficiency, since it avoids the need for outer aggregation:

```
select 
    t.tag_id, 
    t.tag_name, 
    (select count(*) from tags_x tx1 where tx1.tag_id = t.tag_id) no_questions
from tags t
inner join tags_x tx on tx.tag_id = t.tag_id
where tx.question_id = ?
```

This gives you an overall count of questions per tag. If you want a count for questions other than the current one, you can substract 1 from the result, or refine the `where` condition of the subquery:

```
select 
    t.tag_id, 
    t.tag_name, 
    (select count(*) from tags_x tx1 where tx1.tag_id = t.tag_id and tx1.question_id <> tx.question_id) no_questions
from tags t
inner join tags_x tx on tx.tag_id = t.tag_id
where tx.question_id = ?
```

Comment: Top code worked perfectly!  Subquery - Didn't know you could do that!  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

When you include `tags.tag_id` in the `SELECT` clause, MySql will implicitly include that as part of the `GROUP BY`. This violates the ansi standard, btw, which would not allow this query at all.

Maybe you wanted `count(tags_x.tag_id)`.

```
SELECT tags.tag_id, tag_name, count(tags_x.tag_id) AS num
FROM tags 
LEFT JOIN tags_x ON tags.tag_id = tags_x.tag_id 
WHERE tags_x.question_id = ? 
GROUP BY tags.tag_id, tags.tag_name
```

Comment: Tried your above code modification and got the same result.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking that we need *two* references to the `tag_x` cross reference table, one to get the tags related to our question, and another to get *all* the references to the same tag.

To get the `tag_name` returned, we need a join to the `tag` table.

Something like this:

```
SELECT t.tag_name
     , t.tag_id
     , COUNT(c.tag_id) AS cnt_references
  FROM tags_x q
  JOIN tags_x c
    ON c.tag_id = t.tag_id
  JOIN tags 
    ON t.tag_id = q.tag_id
 WHERE q.question_id = ?
 GROUP
    BY t.tag_name
     , t.tag_id
 ORDER
    BY t.tag_name
     , t.tag_id
```

If we don't need to return `tag_name`, we could avoid the join to the `tag` table, and just do something like this:

```
SELECT q.tag_id
     , COUNT(c.tag_id) AS cnt_references
  FROM tags_x q
  JOIN tags_x c
    ON c.tag_id = t.tag_id
 WHERE q.question_id = ?
 GROUP
    BY q.tag_id
 ORDER
    BY q.tag_id
```

It might be faster to do that, in an inline view, and then join to the `tag` table later. This should give equivalent result as first query.

```
SELECT t.tag_name
     , t.tag_id
     , r.cnt_references
  FROM ( -- inline view to count references, one row per tag_id
         SELECT q.tag_id
              , COUNT(c.tag_id) AS cnt_references
           FROM tags_x q
           JOIN tags_x c
             ON c.tag_id = t.tag_id
          WHERE q.question_id = ?
          GROUP
             BY q.tag_id
       ) r
  JOIN tags t
    ON t.tag_id = r.tag_id
 ORDER
    BY t.tag_name
     , t.tag_id
```